# How to built three input OR gate using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, logical-or

I am having dataframe df with 3 inputs (A,B,C) as listed below

```
A   B   C
0   0   0
0   0   1
0   1   0
0   1   1
1   0   0
1   0   1
1   1   0
1   1   1
```

I want built logicial or gate and have sample output like shown below

```
A   B   C   Output
0   0   0   0
0   0   1   1
0   1   0   1
0   1   1   1
1   0   0   1
1   0   1   1
1   1   0   1
1   1   1   1
```

How can this be done in pandas

Comment: Cant see picture，can u put ur data and code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to evaluate `df.A | df.B | df.C`.

```py
df['OR_Gate'] = df.A | df.B | df.C
```

Note: If the values in columns A, B, C are strings of 0's and 1's, then do one of the following:

```py
# Method-1: 
#   Convert the strings into int and then evaluate OR_Gate: 
#   This changes the value-types in the columns A, B, C
df = df.astype('int')
df['OR_Gate'] = df.A | df.B | df.C
# Method-2: 
#   This will not change the original data type in columns A, B, C
#   But will correctly evaluate 'OR_Gate'.
df['OR_Gate'] = df.A.astype(int) | df.B.astype(int) | df.C.astype(int)
# Method-3: 
#   If you want your final output to be in boolean form.
df['OR_Gate'] = df.A.astype(bool) | df.B.astype(bool) | df.C.astype(bool)
```

### Detailed Solution

```py
import pandas as pd

# Dummy data
A = [0]*4 + [1]*4
B = [0]*2 + [1]*2 + [0]*2 + [1]*2
C = [0, 1]*4
# Make Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C})
# Update 'OR_Gate' Output
df['OR_Gate'] = df.A | df.B | df.C
df
```

**Output**:

```
   A  B  C  OR_Gate
0  0  0  0        0
1  0  0  1        1
2  0  1  0        1
3  0  1  1        1
4  1  0  0        1
5  1  0  1        1
6  1  1  0        1
7  1  1  1        1
```

Comment: @Rahulrajan only if you coerce the strings to true and false...

Comment: Let's test that theory. It may require some change. But what kind of string do you have? are those strings of 1's and 0's?

Comment: @CypherX,  I have True or False . Should I dummy code the True to 1 and False to 0  to make this work. Or is there another easy way

Comment: If you have `True` or `False`, then just use `df.A.astype(bool) | df.B.astype(bool) | df.C.astype(bool)`. This will convert 0's and 1's into False/True and also, strings of 0's and 1's and strings of True/False into boolean True/False and then evaluate the OR-Gate.

Comment: @Rahulrajan Please consider **`accepting`** and **`upvoting`** the solution, if applicable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can require [all](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) values meet the condition.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0,0],[0,0,1], [0,1,0], [0,0,0]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df['Output'] = df.eq(False).all(1).astype(int)

df

Out[1]: 
   A  B  C  Output
0  0  0  0       0
1  0  0  1       1
2  0  1  0       1
3  0  0  0       0
```

Comment: @Micheal Gardner , will it work work with strings as well